# Is there a way to convert Python to R?

Tags: python, r, converters

Hey I am trying to convert my python code to R and can't seem to figure out the last part of the recursion. If anyone who has experience in both languages could help that would be great!

```
def robber(nums):
    if len(nums) == 0: return 0
    elif len(nums) <= 2: return max(nums)
    else:
        A = [nums[0], max(nums[0:2])]
        for i in range(2, len(nums)):
            A.append(max(A[i-1], A[i-2] + nums[i]))
    return A[-1]
```

Above is the Python version and below is my attempt so far on converting to R

```
robbing <- function(nums) {
    if (length(nums) == 0){
        result <- 0      
    }
    else if(length(nums) <= 2){
        result <- max(nums)     
    }
    else{
      a <- list(nums[0], max(nums(0:2)))
      for (i in range(2, length(nums))){
          result <- max(a[i-1], a[i-2] + nums[i])
      }
    }
    #result <- a[-1]
}
```

Comment: As best I can see from your code, your remaining problem is how to reference the last element of `A`.  This should be a trivial look-up.  Similarly, reconfiguring the logic so that you assign that value only when the previous clauses fail, is a simple `else if / else` addition.  What problem have I missed?

Comment: `nums(0:2)` should be `nums[0:2]` to subset, not try to call a function called `nums`. Also, R is 1-indexed and has inclusive end-points, so you might want to to check `nums[0:2]` isn't meant to be `nums[1:2]` (maybe?). I suspect `a <- list(...` should also be `a <- c(...` instead. Your function doesn't return anything either at the moment. You'll need to add `return(...)` statements similar to what python has, though R implicitly returns an object if you just put e.g. `max(nums)` as a final line without `<-` assigning it.

Comment: Could you please share `dput(nums)` to test the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

1. You are zero-indexing your vectors. R is 1-indexed (first element of `y` is `y[1]` not `y[0]`.
2. Ranges (slices in python) in R are **inclusive**. Eg: `0:2 = c(0, 1, 2)` while python is right-exclusive `0:2 = [0, 1]`.
3. R uses minus elements to "remove" elements of vectors, while Python uses these to extract from reverse order. Eg: `y[-1] = y[2:length(y)]` in R.
4. R's `range` function is not the same as Python's `range` function. The equivalent in `R` would be `seq` or `a:b` (example `3:n`). Not again that it is right-inclusive while pythons is right-exclusive!
5. You are not storing your intermediary results in `a` as you are doing in python. You need to do this at run-time

And last: R functions will return the last evaluation by default. So there is no need to explicitly use `return`. This is not a problem per-say, but something that can make code look cleaner (or less clean in some cases). So one option to fix you problem would be:

```
robber <- function(nums){
  n <- length(nums) # <= Only compute length **once** =>
  if(n == 0)
    0 # <= Returned because no more code is run after this =>
  else if(n <= 2)
    max(nums) # <= Returned because no more code is run after this =>
  else{
    a <- numeric(n) # <= pre-allocate our vector =>
    a[1:2] <- cummax(nums[1:2]) # <= Cummax instead of c(nums[1], max(nums[1:2])) =>
    for(i in 3:n){ # <= Note that we start at 3, because of R's 1-indexing =>
      a[i] <- max(a[i - 1], a[i - 2] + nums[i])
    }
    a[n]
  }
}
```

Note 3 things:

1. I use that R vectors are 1-indexed, and my range goes from `3` as a consequence of this.
2. I pre-allocate my `a` vector (here using `numeric(n)`). R vector expansion is **slow** while python lists are constant in time-complexity. So preallocation is the recommended way to go in all cases.
3. I extract my length **once** and store it in a variable. `n <- length(nums)`. It is inherently unnecessary to evaluate this multiple times, and it is recommended to store these intermediary results in a variable. This goes for any language such as R, Python and even in compild languages such as C++ (while for the latter, in many cases the compiler is smart enough to not recompute the result).

Last I use `cummax` where I can. I feel there is an optimized way to get your result almost immediately using vectorization, but I can't quite see it.

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation helped out a lot. I very rarely use r so when my friend asked me to convert this for him I was struggling and needed a little advice.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad i could help. Make sure to mark the answer as "the answer" by clickin the checkmark right under the up-vote button, if it answered your questions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid to use a list. Because appending lists is slow. (Especially in R! - Vector is much better. But we don't need any sequence and indexing, if we use variables like I show you here).
You don't need to build a list.
All you need to keep in memory is the previous
and the preprevious value for res.

```
def robber(nums, res=0, prev=0, preprev=0): # local vars predefined here
    for x in nums:
        prev, preprev = res, prev
        res = max(prev, preprev + x)
    return res
```

This python function does the same like your given. (Try it out!).

In R this would be:

```
robber <- function(nums, res=0, prev=0, preprev=0) {
  for (x in nums) {
    preprev <- prev
    prev <- res       # correct order important!
    res <- max(prev, preprev + x)
  }
  res
}
```

Taking the local variable definitions into the argument list saves in R 3 lines of code, therefore I did it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can change `result` to `return()` and renaming object `a` outside the function, also change `len` to `length()` by the end of the function.

```
a <- list(nums[0], max(nums(0:2)))

robbing <- function(nums) {
  if (length(nums) == 0){
    return(0)    
  }
  else if(length(nums) <= 2){
    return(max(nums))     
  }
  else{
    
    for (i in range(2, length(nums))){
      return(max(a[i-1], a[i-2] + nums[i]))
    }
  }
  return(a[length(a)])
}
```

Comment: Hi @AlvaroMartinez, A few pointers to your answer: `a` should be stored inside the function `robbing`, and `range` should be replaced by `seq` or `a:b`. Also the for loop should not `return` in each iteration to be compliant with the python version in the question. :-)